# How to get a synchronuous result from an HTTP request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, http-post, synchronous

I am writing a node module as a wrapper around a Python module (to make that module available from node.js). This module works as a standalone script or as an HTTP server.

When getting data from that script/server my function needs to *return* a value and can't *do* something in a callback function. At least that's how I understand it.
(One possible client is a gitbook-plugin, and when that encounters a "block" it has to call the plugin->my-client-module and insert its return value into the generated HTML document.)

So either I'm seeing something wrong because I'm too new to Node.js (coming from Python) or I need a way to make the HTTP request synchronous.

With the standalone script I can easily do it using ChildProcess.spawnSync, but not in an HTTP request.

Well, I know people are always recommending to do things asynchronously in Node, so I'd also be happy about pointers how to achieve my goal that way. As said I expect clients of my module to pass me some data, pass that along to invoke the script or do a POST request on the server and return the processed data to the client.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to fetch data when a module is required instead of having a module that gives you an object that you can call an initialize function on and which then returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve synchronous HTTP requests using web-workers.
Here is more info on this topic:
https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Example_Synchronous_HTTP_request_from_a_Worker

---

### Edit:

You can make synchronous requests from Node.Js. The following module should help:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly. Assuming I find a module to use workers in Node (the example is from Mozilla), this doesn't *return* a value synchronously. If I'm not mistaken that approach would allow me to encapsulate the actual HTTP request in a synchronous call but from the perspective of the caller this would still seem asynchronous. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, and why. If you can provide more detail on the issue, I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, the use case that triggered my work (others are conceivable as well): I'm writing a Gitbook plugin (http://toolchain.gitbook.com/plugins/). Whenever a template block is found during the generation of a page gitbook calls into the plugin, passing the template to a function and expects the replacement string as return value. When I need to make an HTTP request to generate that replacement string this request needs to be synchronous because I have to return a value. As far as I can see I can't use a callback function for this. ...

Comment: ... There is another level of complexity (but I'm not sure it really adds something new): What I'm *actually* writing is a generic node.js module that will do the HTTP request for any client. The Gitbook plugin will call a function in the new node module, but of course it also has to expect a synchronous return value.

Comment: `sync-request` seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you. Now I'm having difficutlies getting the actual request to work properly (getting a message "Parse Error" out of the response object), but this is another issue. So I can consider this one closed.